# Targeting form success with JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

I'm using vanilla JS (no jQuery!) in a Node app and I'm trying to target a "success" state through JS. Please take a look at the attached GIF, and you can see that what I want to do is display a success-message once a form has been submitted. However, this message displays as result of a click-event and a setTimeout via JS, thus activating both when the form is filled out correctly and when it is not.

[image: explainer]

My code:

```
// Contact form submit effect
document.querySelector('#contact-submit').addEventListener('click', function() {

  // Load spinner effect
  document.querySelector('#contact-submit').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>'

  // Get height and width of container for use in replacement div
  const contactHeight = document.querySelector('#contactContainer').offsetHeight;
  const contactWidth = document.querySelector('#contactContainer').offsetWidth;

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Remove form elements 
    const children = document.querySelector('#contactContainer #contact').childNodes;
    children.forEach(element => {
      if(element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'fieldset') {
        element.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });

    // Create message DIV and content
    const contactMsg = document.createElement('div');
    contactMsg.classList.add('contactMsg');
    contactMsg.innerHTML = `
    <h1>Tak for din besked! </h1>
    <p>Vi vender tilbage hurtigst muligt.</p>
    <img src="mail_sent.svg">`
    
    // Append message to DOM
    document.querySelector('#contactContainer').appendChild(contactMsg);

    // Set height and width of message to reflect size of previous content
    contactMsg.parentNode.style.height = `${contactHeight}px`;
    contactMsg.parentNode.style.width = `${contactWidth}px`;
  }, 1000)
});
```

One workaround I can think of is to use if-statements that looks to see if all fields are filled, and then use regular expressions to check if the inputs are valid. However, this seems like wet code, when the HTML5 already has this built-in functionality. Another way could maybe be to run the message-function from the server.js in my Node application, but as far as I know I can't run DOM-related functions in Node.

**TLDR**; How would I go about targeting a succes-state in plain JS in order to display a message only on a succesful form submit event?

Comment: Ideally you should control the submit process... are you doing an ajax request? If yes, you should call the success state on the success callback of the request.

But in your case it looks simpler to the frontend just to do a regular form post request and redirect to the success page in the server

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GustavoSantiago. I am not using Ajax. I'm using a node application where I have my POST request in server.js which is then called by my form via action="/message". Thanks to user "osynkad" the form now works as intended - however, the page keeps loading ad infinitum. Do you have any ideas that does not include a "res.redirect" in my server.js? I would like to avoid a page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @osynkad the form is now working as intended. I targeted the form and its submit event instead of the click event on the button.

However, this solution resulted in the page reloading ad infinitum. Instead of rewriting everything with AJAX and jQuery in order to avoid this reload, apparantly it is possible to target an invisible iFrame to avoid page reload. I have no idea why, but it works.

Like so:

```
<form id="contact" target="contact_iframe" action="/message" method="post" role="form">
  //....
</form>
<iframe id="contact_iframe" name="contact_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Now, the success message only displays on a succesful form submit, and the page does not reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead of listening to the button click event listen to the form submit event the function wont actually run unless all fields with the `required`-attribute is filled.

More info regarding submit event found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event).

And more info on client-side validation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: This is great. I put the eventlistener on the form and listened for the submit event. Great simple fix. I'm not sure how I missed it.

However, now the tab reloads ad infinitum. I tried .preventDefault() but then of course the form doesn't submit. Any ideas?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should do the trick to avoid your form causing a page reload. Does none of the code beneath your `preventDefault()` run?

Comment: The code runs, meaning the visuals are now as they should be, but the form does not actually submit. The form should activate my server.js POST request (app.post) via the HTML action="/message", and I guess e.preventDefault() blocks that?

Comment: Yeah, `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default event functionality. You should be able to access all form input data from your event arg and use the built in `fetch` API to make POST requests to your backend. I'm not too familiar with the default submit functionality unfortunately.